# Enable multitouch on all Elements windows phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, multi-touch

How can I enable multitouch support for all elements in windows phone? So, for example, if had two `sliders` and couple of buttons, how can I allow all three to be manipulated by different simultanous effects on the touch screen.

I saw couple of tutorials online, but I believe they are outdated:

- [Multi-Touch Manipulation Events in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff898416.aspx)
- [Windows Phone 7 Multi-Touch Drawing Demo](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP7MultiTouchDrawing-4513213a)

Comment: Can you describe what you want in more detail?

Comment: @ToniPetrina  just want to be able to touch multiple elements (buttons,sliders, etc) while holding another element. So for example, with one finger i am moving a slider and with the other figure I want to press a button.

Comment: Interesting idea. I don't know if slider can handle losing focus like that. Unless you will handle everything yourself, I am afraid that there is no easy way. Maybe this thread is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286229/pressing-multiple-buttons-simultaneously.

Comment: @ToniPetrina It doesnt seem to work. The button, if pressed at the same time as another, isnt called.