# How can I detect 2 button pressed at the same time?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a winphone app with several buttons on a page. I want to be able to press them two (or more) at a time. Unfortunately when I press two buttons (with 2 fingers), only one of them gets the click or tap events and the other one does not. How can I know that 2 buttons are pressed?

Comment: are you going to have different events occurring for each and every button?

Comment: same event handler for all buttons, but I need 2 separate events if I press 2 buttons

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pressing multiple buttons simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286229/pressing-multiple-buttons-simultaneously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the post below, you could achieve this by using `Touch.FrameReported` event.

[Pressing multiple buttons simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286229/)

Answer (score 0):

What underlying framework are you using ? Is it C++ or C# ? XNA or WPF/XAML ? WP7 or WP8?

As Kulasangar pointed Touch.FrameReported should be the way to do it in C#.

For XNA you will have to enable the MultiTouch and then use the TouchCollection class. That will give you access to multiple touches.

In DirectX you might have to use managed C++ and listen to one of the system events. 
Things might change based on the platform ( WP7 or WP8 )